# Logstash mutate gsub not working inside "if" statement

Tags: logstash

i have an issue using logstash mutate filter gsub.

**Required**

Remove "ZC" characters of a field and coverting it into float

```
{
      "field" => "12.343,40ZC",
      "@timestamp" => 2020-01-06T23:00:00.000Z
}
```

**Expected output**

```
{
       "field" => "-12343,40",
       "@timestamp" => 2020-01-06T23:00:00.000Z
}
```

**Code not working**

```
filter{
  if "ZC" in "field" {
    mutate { gsub => ["field","ZC",""] } 
  }
}
```

**Code working**

```
filter{
    mutate { gsub => ["field","ZC",""] } 
}
```

I need the "if" statement because depends if the two characters exist inside the field to make a positive or negative float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conditional is wrong, if you use `"field"` logstash understands that as a string with the value `field`, the [correct way](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#logstash-config-field-references) is to use the format `[field]`.

Change your conditional to the following.

```
filter {
  if "ZC" in [field] {
    mutate { gsub => ["field","ZC",""] } 
  }
}
```